# uploading all files from a specified path dynamically in nodejs, express and angular1.x

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I'm using NodeJS, express and Angular1.x, how can i upload/move all the files from a specific folder by giving the path of this folder

how do i handle this in either angular or node

is that using

```
var fs = require('fs') module
```

or

```
var multer = require('multer')
```

I know something like the below code but I should be able to move all the files from that location to another location

```
var fs = require("fs");
var fileName = "foo.txt";

fs.exists(fileName, function(exists) {
  if (exists) {
    fs.stat(fileName, function(error, stats) {
      fs.open(fileName, "r", function(error, fd) {
        var buffer = new Buffer(stats.size);

        fs.read(fd, buffer, 0, buffer.length, null, function(error, bytesRead, buffer) {
          var data = buffer.toString("utf8", 0, buffer.length);

          console.log(data);
          fs.close(fd);
        });
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

using the angular plug-in it has examples showing using this plug-in in nodejs, express

https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload